# Regarding compile time error in Map

Tags: java, list, dictionary, linkedhashmap

Please don't consider this question as duplicate although I have a similiar question earlier but this time it is different..

```
Map m = new LinkedHashMap();
m.put ("123", "23"); 
m.put ("323", "23");
m.put ("153", "23");
m.put ("623", "23");
m.put ("125", "23");
m.put ("122", "24");
m.put ("167", "24");
m.put ("173", "24");
m.put ("113", "25");
```

Now my query is is that I need to find out the that how many scripts are there associated with patient Id 23 as seen above 5 total different scripts are there,

I have done this..

```
List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(String str: m.keySet())
        {
            if(m.get(str).equals("23")) {
                keys.add(str);
            }
        }
```

but it shows complier error cannot convert object to string please advise.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
Map m = new LinkedHashMap();
```

to

```
Map <String,String>m = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
```

So it knows that it's a map of strings pointing to strings.

Answer (score 1):

"cannot convert object to string please advise" <-- this is normal since your `Map` declaration does not allow for this.

You should declare:

```
Map<String, String> m = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined your Map as a Map of Strings. Therefore, the keyset you're iterating over is a set of Objects.
Try changing your Map declaration to:

```
Map<String, String> m = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
```